# Disastery recovery after a mistaken use of Export

Tags: export

I meant to export on the file
`"report.txt"`
the files list
`{ "file1", "file2", ...}`, mostly .pdf and .djvu.
Erroneously just now I have exported the `"report.txt"` string on each of files
`"file1"`, `"file2"`, ...

Does exist any way to remedy and get back my files ?

( Windows Xp, Mathematica 8)

Comment: If they've been overwritten, then probably not. Very likely the first block of those files has been erased for good, although you may be able to recover other blocks with file recovery software. But if they were files with important headers (like .pdf, .zip, etc.) then they've almost certainly been irreparably corrupted even if you could recover most of the blocks intact.

Comment: Unless you have recent enough backups of your hard drive. Good luck.

Comment: You have my sympathies. Newer versions of Mathematica have the option `OverwriteTarget`, but it doesn't default to `False` AFAIK. It would probably be a good thing if it did.